# Appengine Deferred task limited to 60 seconds

Tags: java, google-app-engine

In Google Appengine documentation it says that tasks are limited to 10 minutes. However when I run deferred tasks they die in 60 seconds. I couldn't find anywhere this to be mentioned.

Does it mean that Appengine deferred tasks are limited to 60 seconds, or maybe I am doing something wrong?

UPDATE: The first task is triggered from request, but I am not waiting for it to return (and how could I anyway, there are no callbacks). The subsequent ones
I am triggering, kind of recursively, from within the task itself.

```
DeferredTask df = new QuoteReader(params);
QueueFactory.getDefaultQueue().add(withPayload(df));
```

Many of them just work, but for the ones which reach 1 minute limit  I get `ApiProxy$ApiDeadlineExceededException`

> com.googlecode.objectify.cache.Pending completeAllPendingFutures: Error cleaning up pending Future: com.googlecode.objectify.cache.CachingAsyncDatastoreService$3@17f5ddc
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$ApiDeadlineExceededException: The API call datastore_v3.Get() took too long to respond and was cancelled.

Another thing I noticed, this affects the other request to that server happening at the same time and that goes down with `DeadlineExceededException`.

Comment: What is the exact error you're getting?

Comment: are you running the task in the background, or triggering it on a request and waiting for the task to finish before returning the request to the user? If the latter, that's incorrect, requests have a 60 second limit regardless of anything else.

Comment: Please show the code for how you're triggering these tasks.

Comment: please, see updated description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is coming from a Datastore operation that is exceeding 60s.  It's not really related to Taskqueue deadlines as such.  You are correct that they are 10 minutes (see [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/backends/#Java_Properties_of_backends))

However as per [Old related issue](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4432) (maybe it changed to 60s since)

> From Google: Even though offline requests can currently live up to 10 minutes (and background instances can live forever) datastore queries can still only live for 30 seconds.

It seems from the exception that your code completed and it's Objectify (later in the request filters) that's actually where the timeout occurs. I'd suggest you split up your data operations so datastore queries are quicker and if necessary use .now() on your data operations so exceptions occur in your code.